# Do you know batch log processing tools for hadoop (zohmg alternatives)?

Tags: hadoop, olap, hbase, log-analysis

Since the zohmg project seems to be dead (no new commits since nov 2009), I would like to know if any of you used/uses it (with successful results). Or if you know anything about future of this project.

And if not, is there any alternative for this project. I'm looking for tool that will help to extract data from (apache) logs (using Hadoop as a batch processing system), store it into HBase, help with querying this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cascading is very often used for this. It also provides adapters for HBase.

Examples can be found here
http://github.com/cwensel/cascading.samples

HBase integration
http://www.cascading.org/modules.html